# Put TextBox Value into Variable

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

I want to save a Value from GUI TextBox in a Variable after i pressed the Button.

My Code so far:

```vb
    Dim TestSpalte As Long
    TestSpalte = TextBox1.Value
    MsgBox "Test " & TestSpalte
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get value from an **`UserForm`**

```
UserForm1.TextBox1.Text
```

To get value from a **`WorkSheet`**

```
Worksheets("MySheetName").TextBox1.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
Dim TestSpalte As Long
```

with:

```
Dim TestSpalte As String
```